# Do the runes appear in-universe?

Tags: madoka-magica

So we know what the runes [translate to](http://wiki.puella-magi.net/Deciphering_the_runes) in *Puella Magi Madoka Magica*. Since the runes appear all over the place like on walls and when a witch appears, the Puella Magi must be aware of the runes, which are also on their rings as [their names](http://wiki.puella-magi.net/Runes:Rebellion) (see the images which show their rings).

I am wondering, in-universe, what are the runes? Are they magical, thus making up a [runic magic system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runic_magic)? Are they the native language of the Incubators? Or are they something else entirely?

Comment: I can attest that none of Oriko / Kazumi / TDS / Rebellion nor the original Hanokage manga address the question of what the in-universe nature of the runes is. There could be something in Tart / Suzune / Sadness Prayer / Majuu-hen, though; I haven't kept up with those. (Or in production materials/interviews and so forth, too, of course.)